# Button added to toolbar is not working in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

```
Ext.define('CCCC.view.Header', {
extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
requires: ['CCCC.view.header.MasterLogo',
            'Ext.button.Button'],
alias: 'widget.mainheader',
itemId : 'header',
width: '100%',
height: 100,
renderTo: document.body,




initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.items = [

        {
            xtype: 'tbfill' 
        },
        {
            xtype: 'tbseparator'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Logout',
            itemId: 'logout',
            listeners: {
               handler: function() {
                    var me = button.up('WidgetName');
                    me.fireEvent('logoutClicked', button, e);
                    Ext.log('logout clicked');
               }
            }
        },
```

i have added the logout button to the toolbar as xtype. it is showing as lable , not able to click the "logout" button. Please let me know why "logout" button is not clickable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`handler`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler) should be in the button config, not in the button's `listener` config:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Logout',
    itemId: 'logout',
    handler: function() {
        var me = button.up('WidgetName');
        me.fireEvent('logoutClicked', button, e);
        Ext.log('logout clicked');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a listener, you should listen to the [`click`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-event-click) event instead:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Logout',
    itemId: 'logout',
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            var me = button.up('WidgetName');
            me.fireEvent('logoutClicked', button, e);
            Ext.log('logout clicked');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. the button itself is not clickable. its just showing the button label. how to make button as clickable.

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5vr) based on the code you've provided and it seems to work fine there. Maybe provide your own fiddle where the problem can be reproduced?